# Is there a Linq operation to retrieve specific items from a list of items where the item has a property value for a property which should be unique?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<>` of custom objects. This custom type has a property called `Name` which should be unique among the list. In other words, no 2 items items in the list should have the same value for their `Name` property.

When I validate this list, I want to retrieve the offending items. Is there a Linq operation which will allow me to do this?

I want to have something like

```
listOfItems.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(/*anything else in this list with the same value for name */)
```

Basically, I am trying to avoid checking the entire list against every item in the list (in a nested foreach):

```
private IList<ICustomObject> GetDuplicatedTypeNames(IList<ICustomObjects> customObjectsToFindDuplicatesIn)
    {
        var duplicatedList = new List<ICustomObject>();

        foreach(var customObject in customObjectsToFindDuplicatesIn)
            foreach(var innerCustomObject in customObjectsToFindDuplicatesIn)
                if (customObject == innerCustomObject && customObject .Name.Equals(innerCustomObject.Name))
                    duplicatedList.Add(customObject);

        return duplicatedList;
    }
```

(EDIT) NOTE: I am constrained to using a List<> by domain rules and using a Dictionary<> is not an option.

Comment: It seems you have a bug in your original loop. It should read: if (customObject != innerCustomObject && ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get names of duplicates:

```
 var duplicates = listOfItems
        .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

**Edit:** Get duplicate items:

```
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: This will only return the Names of the duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a Dictionary instead of a List then, with the Name property as the Key? That way, you can't [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) duplicate names to the collection at all, as an exception would be thrown.

Furthermore, you can use the [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) method to test if a name is already in the Dictionary before adding it.

The advantage of this approach is that it's much faster than scanning the List for duplicates.

Comment: My List is a the back end DataSource of a visual grid. The user edits values in the grid and I want validation to happen on the fly. A Dictionary would unnecessarily complicate the DataSource. Also I am restricted by this rule because of how the domain model works.

Comment: From the description, it seems to me that there's a `List` that allows dupes, and that the asker want to know what these dupes are

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know that your situation didn't allow the use of a Dictionary.. but you should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of objects

```
class foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

class fooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<foo>
{
    public bool Equals(foo x, foo y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}


var duplicates = listOfItems
.GroupBy(x => x, new fooEqualityComparer())
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.SelectMany(g => g);
```